# Why I'm getting access violation errors with my Vertex Buffer Object?

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

This are my typdefs/global variables:

```
static GLuint GL15_vbo[2];

typedef struct {
    fvec3 pos;
    fvec3 col;
    fvec2 uv;
} MyVertex;

typedef struct {
    GLuint a;
    GLuint b;
    GLuint c;
} TriFace;
```

This is my initialization code:

```
glGenBuffers(2, (GLuint *)&GL15_vbo);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL15_vbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL15_vbo[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(faces), faces, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

This is my render code:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (const void *)(offsetof(MyVertex, pos)));
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (const void *)(offsetof(MyVertex, col)));
glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (const void *)(offsetof(MyVertex, uv)));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL15_vbo[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL15_vbo[1]);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

for (int iface = 0; iface < 12; iface++) {
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (const void *)(iface * sizeof(TriFace)));
}

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Can you tell me, what's wrong with my code? I'm getting the access violation at glDrawElements. It works well with simple Vertex Arrays (so the data arrays are initialized well). Thank you.

Comment: is this really c++? or it is C ? `static GL15_vbo[2];` would not compile in c++.

Comment: [The last parameter to glDrawElements should be the pointer to array of indices](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml).

Comment: @UmNyobe Nonsense. The 4th parameter of `glDrawElements` has to be the a pointer to the array of indices, if no named buffer object is bound.  
If a named buffer object is bound (as in this case), then the parameter is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store. [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 10.4. DRAWING COMMANDS USING VERTEX ARRAYS; page 419](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have 12 faces. I get access violation even on the first loop.

Comment: @UmNyobe I just cut the datatype away. `static GLuint GL15_vbo[2];` is correct. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter of [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml), [`glColorPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColorPointer.xml) and [`glTexCoordPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoordPointer.xml) has to be a pointer to the first vertex coordinate respectively the first attribute.

If a non-zero named buffer object is bound, then the parameter is treated as a byte offset into the array buffer object's data store.

You want to use an named array buffer and the parameters are the proper offsets of the attributes. But the buffer object is not bound at this point, because you do `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` after creating and initializing the buffer object's data store.
The buffer is bound again only after specifying the attributes:

> ```
> glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (const void *)(offsetof(MyVertex, pos)));
> glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (const void *)(offsetof(MyVertex, col)));
> glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (const void *)(offsetof(MyVertex, uv)));
>
> glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL15_vbo[0]);
> ```

It has to be:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL15_vbo[0]);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (const void *)(offsetof(MyVertex, pos)));
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (const void *)(offsetof(MyVertex, col)));
glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (const void *)(offsetof(MyVertex, uv)));
```

Comment: Thank you! This has solved the issue. I didn't get that the attributes are attached to the buffer.